# Scraping dynamic content from website in near-realtime

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I’m trying to implement a web scraper scraping dynamically updated content from a website in near-realtime.

Let’s take https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/ as an example and assume I want to continuously get the current time at my home location.
My solution right now is as follows: Get the rendered page content every second and extract the time using bs4. Working Code:

```
import asyncio
import bs4
import pyppeteer

def get_current_time(content):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml")
    clock = soup.find(class_="my-city__digitalClock")
    hour_minutes = clock.contents[3].next_element
    seconds = clock.contents[5].next_element
    return hour_minutes + ":" + seconds

async def main():
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/")
    for _ in range(30):
        content = await page.content()
        print(get_current_time(content))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What I would like to do instead is: React only when the time is updated on the page. Reasons: Faster reaction and less computationally intensive (especially when monitoring multiple pages that may update in irregular intervals smaller or much larger than a second).

I got / tried the following three ideas how to solve this, but I don’t know how to do continue. There might also a much simpler / more elegant approach:

**1) Intercepting network responses using pyppeteer**

This does not seem to work, since there is no more network activity after initially loading the page (except from advertising), as I can see in the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

**2) Reacting to custom events on the page**

Using the “Event Listener Breakpoints” in the “Sources” tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I can stop the JavaScript code execution on various events (e.g. the “Set innerHTML” event).

Is it possible to do something like this using pyppeteer, provide some context information about the event (e.g. which element is updated with which new text)?

It seems to be possible using JavaScript and puppeteer (see https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/custom-event.js), but I think pyppeteer does not provide this functionality (I could not find it in the API Reference).

**3) Overriding a function in the JavaScript code of the page**

Override a relevant function and intercept the relevant data (which are provided to that function as a parameter).

This idea is inspired by this blogpost: https://antoinevastel.com/javascript/2019/06/10/monitor-js-execution.html

Entire code for the blogpost: https://github.com/antoinevastel/blog-post-monitor-js/blob/master/monitorExecution.js

I tried around a bit, but my JavaScript seems too limited to even just override a function in one of the javascripts used by the page.

Comment: It can be done with a mutation observer, but honestly you're better off getting the time once and incrementing it every second or just subtracting start time from current time.

Comment: Thank you. A mutation observer looks very interesting. The clock is just a simple, reproducible example. In the real application, the content changes in irregular intervals. Are there any serious disadvantages of using a mutation observer?

Comment: Just that it can be messy to implement. Another idea if the data comes from a xhr is just use the response event.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). I am using the [Chrome webdriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) via [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) but you can modify this to use whatever you prefer.

First, all of our imports

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Create our `driver` object with the `headless` parameter so that the browser window doesn't open.

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Define a function that accepts a `WebElement` to extract the clock time.

```py
def getTimeString(myClock: WebElement) -> str:
    hourMinute = myClock.find_element(By.XPATH, "span[position()=2]").text
    seconds = myClock.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "my-city__seconds").text
    return f"{hourMinute}:{seconds}"
```

Get the page and extract the clock `WebElement`

```py
driver.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/")
myClock = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "my-city__digitalClock")
```

Finally, implement our loop

```py
last = None
while True:
    now = getTimeString(myClock)
    if now == last:
        continue
    print(now)
    last = now
```

Before your logic concludes, be sure to run `driver.quit()` to clean up.

Output

```xml
05:27:56
05:27:57
05:27:58
```

Comment: Thank you. Selenium is not an option, though, because it is not asyncio-compatible. Also, I would prefer to react only when something relevant changes on the page ("await some_relevant_change") and sit in idle the rest of the time (processing other tasks in the meantime using asyncio). However, since you are not parsing the entire webpage on every iteration, your solution is probably far more efficient than the example I posted.

Comment: Something very similar can be done using pyppeteer: ```hour_minute = await page.querySelector("#c83")``` and then ```await page.evaluate("(element) => element.textContent", hour_minutes)```. Not yet what I want, because it requires frequent checking for changes, but better than the current solution.

Comment: I hope it was still helpful anyway, even if not the answer :)

Comment: Definitely yes!